# Error when trying to connect Corda Node using RPC

Tags: corda

I am getting the following exception on the Node log, when i try to make a RPC connection from the client .The client.start() method seems to be stuck .  The code is as follows. I am running this code from within a servlet hosted in Jetty .

```
        final NetworkHostAndPort nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse("localhost:10008");
        final CordaRPCClient client = new CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress, CordaRPCClientConfiguration.DEFAULT);
        // Can be amended in the com.example.Main file.
        CordaRPCConnection clientConn= client.start("user1","password");

        rpcOps =clientConn.getProxy();

        rpcOps.waitUntilNetworkReady();
```

Below is the exception i see in the node log.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:552) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.collections.TypedProperties.getLongProperty(TypedProperties.java:240) ~[artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage.getLongProperty(CoreMessage.java:820) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.CoreMessage.getLongProperty(CoreMessage.java:826) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApiKt.id(RPCApi.kt:353) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApiKt.invocationId(RPCApi.kt:345) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApiKt.replyId(RPCApi.kt:270) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ClientToServer$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:153) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:299) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:79) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:196) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:79) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCServerKt$sam$MessageHandler$5b9bfc45.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:997) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:49) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1120) [artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue in my testing and it turned out that my client library was a different version from the server. The error log shows that server has 3.2. What's the version of RPC you have on the client?

Comment: You are  correct . I had the version as 2.2.0 on the client.